# How to add a privacy URL

Tags: url, facebook-graph-api, privacy

When making an app, where or how do you get a privacy URL? Same with a terms of use URL?

Comment: You don’t “get” those URLs – you have to write the contents of these policies yourself, put them on the web – and then you put the URL to those pages into your app settings, so that the user can read them when he clicks on the links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specify the Privacy/ToU URLs in the "App Details" section of your App Dashboard. Facebook does not provide hosting for this and you should create these pages on your personal/company app development website.

Answer (score 0):

You need privacy policy and terms and conditions and host them on the web. You have basically three options for obtaining these documents:

- Do it by yourself
- Hire a lawyer
- Use an automatic service, like [iubenda](https://www.iubenda.com), that automatically generates a privacy policy optimized for your facebook app (and soon terms and conditions): https://www.iubenda.com/en/facebook (I'm the founder of this service, so feel free to ask any question ;) )